# How do I identify an Interface ID in Watchkit

Tags: ios, watchkit

I am building a story-based navigation with Watchkit.
All "pages" have an identical build: Same labels, images, ...
Depending on the page I want to feed those ui elements with different data via the controller.
So, I a have now three Interface Controllers in my storyboard and one InterfaceController.swift file which is set up as class for the controllers.
I gave each of the storyboard Interface Controllers an 'identifier' via storyboard.
I would like to set different data for the ui elements depending on the value of the identifier.

Is there a way to obtain the value of the 'identifier' in the InterfaceController.swift file in order to decide which data to use?